# containment in a cantor set

Tags: functional-analysis

I said that the following statement was false: If a belongs to the Cantor set and I is an open interval containing a, then I contains at least one other member of the Cantor set.

Unfortunately I am unable to know for sure if I am right or wrong as I do not have the answer key, and am hoping that you could tell me. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct: the Cantor set has no isolated points.

Comment: No, he's not correct, since he said it was false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that every point of the cantor set is an accumulation point with the triadic presentation of the cantor set, so that $$x\in C \iff x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k}$$ 
with $a_k\in\{0,2\}$. Now you take a sequence converging to this $x$ which is in the cantor set.
By showing that every point is an accumulation point you see that there are no isolated points, so it is right.